# How to prove that equilateral triangle formed by cube's corners cannot be fully inserted to this cube

Tags: geometry, proof-verification

I would like to prove that equilateral triangle prescribed by cube's corners and sides equal to $b = a \sqrt{2}$ cannot be inserted into the *interior* of a cube of side $a$. This triangle is presented by figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WydAj.png). [image: equilateral triangle]

My idea to prove this is as follows:

We assume that according to the figure [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0XlA.png) triangle $ABC$ prescribe a sphere of radius $r = a \sqrt{2}$. The position of point $B$ is fixed at the center of sphere and points $A$ and $C$ are on its surface. Right now we can see that if we try to move point $A$ or $C$ on the sphere's surface to the inside of cube, one of them will always goes out or stay at cube's corner. Therefore points $A,C$ can be located only on the cube's corners and cannot both enter a cube.

What you think about this idea?  Also there is any well known proof of this?

[image]

Comment: I think you mean: the equilateral triangle cannot be contained strictly in the interior of the cube. (In fact, it seems likely to me that all three vertices must lie on the boundary, but I have no proof.)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. You are right and I have edited my question to makes it more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Lemma**. The product of lengths of sides of a triangle which lies in the unit cube no more than $2\sqrt{2}$.

**Proof**. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44396/largest-triangle-with-vertices-in-the-unit-cube), the first answer.

Let $a = 1$. Then if your equilateral triangle is inserted into the interior of the cube, we can inflate it and get a triangle with a product of lengths of sides more than $2\sqrt{2}$. We have contradiction.