# Triangle with the area at most $\frac{7}{12}$.

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose that there are $75$  points inside a unit cube such that no three points are co-linear. Prove that it is possible to choose three points from those given above which form a triangle with the area at most $\frac{7}{12}$. How is that possible to get area of the triangle from these given data? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: I'd try to express tetrahedron volume via faces' surface and split the interior of convex hull of the points into tetrahedrons

Comment: Btw this problem seems to be from [link](https://artofproblemsolving.com/downloads/printable_post_collections/4726) where the bound is actually smaller $= \frac{7}{72} \approx 0.09722$

Answer (score 4):

Divide the unit cube into 27 cubes of size $\frac{1}{3} \times \frac{1}{3} \times \frac{1}{3}$.

By the pigeonhole principle, one of these cubes contains 3 out of the 75 points. From the given condition, these points are not collinear. So they form a triangle

In a cube of side $a$, the maximum area of a triangle that can fit in it is $\frac{\sqrt{3}a^2}{2}$.

For side $\frac{1}{3}$, this is $\approx 0.0962 < \frac{7}{12}$

Therefore, these three points form a triangle of area less than $\frac{7}{12}$

Comment: The maximum area that can fit in a cube is $\sqrt{3}a^2\over 2$

Comment: Right. I think the result still holds though. Can you double check?

Comment: @cr001 Sounds perfectly logical to me, but do you know of a nice written proof of that fact anywhere? Tried to search MSE but the search drew a blank.

Comment: It's the maximal equilateral triangle I think. I messed up the calculation before but thanks to @cr001 for pointing that out

Comment: An equilateral triangle with side $s$ has area $\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{4}s^2$. A cube of side $a$ contains an equilateral triangle of side $s=\sqrt{2}a$ which has an area of $\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}a^2$.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales I don't need an example of an equilateral triangle of that area, it is quite clear to me what triangle you are thinking of. I am asking for a proof why it cannot have a bigger area than that.

Comment: It would follow from the argument posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44396/largest-triangle-with-vertices-in-the-unit-cube).

Comment: Also see the [proof](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-maximum-area-of-an-equilateral-triangle-that-will-fit-in-a-cube-of-edge-size-1) offered on Quora.

Comment: It's easy to visualize the fact if you inscribe the cube in a sphere. The equilateral triangle of size $\sqrt{3}\over 2$ will pass throug the center of the sphere.

Comment: As for the double check, the answer seems good to me now.

Comment: @cr001 Excellent, thanks, this works well.

Answer (score 0):

Choose points $(0,0,0)$ and $(1,1,z)$ and $(1,1,0)$. Area of this triangle is $\frac{z}{\sqrt 2}$.

Now choose $z=\frac{7\cdot \sqrt 2}{12}$

There are infinite ways to place the remaining 72 points, so there should exists ways to make that no 3 points are non-colinear.

The remaining points may for example lie in the plane $z=\frac{7\cdot \sqrt 2}{12}$ and form a circular shape.

Comment: The question doesn't say that there needs to be no triangle that has area > $\frac{7}{12}$. It asks that there exists some triangle with area atmost $\frac{7}{12}$